Creating listeners without springboot auto config
I have a usecase where I need to start listeners programmatically based on some configuration at runtime.
I was wondering how to register pulsar listeners at runtime without using the static @PulsarListener annotation.
thank you

The way it currently works is as follows:
The PulsarListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor scans all @PulsarListener and for each one it...

asks the PulsarListenerEndpointRegistrar to register the endpoint to a container factory
registrar in turn asks the PulsarListenerEndpointRegistry to register the endpoint and container factory
registry in turn creates the container (using the factory)
registry handles the lifecycle (start/stop) of all registered containers (i.e. when registry bean is started it spins through and calls start on all registered containers)

This is a more uncommon usecase and as such there is no built-in support for registering containers w/ the registry dynamically after app start.
However, you can create your own container instances and handle the lifecycle methods yourself by manually starting/stopping them (e.g. here).
I will provide a prototype that details several variants of the above in the next 24-48hrs but wanted to get you the above preliminary information quickly.

Here is a sample app that illustrates creating dynamic listener containers at runtime: https://github.com/onobc/spring-pulsar-sample-dynamic-container

Thank you so much @onobc. this is amazing and very helpful. appreciate the details and the example app

You are more than welcome @Gootik. Feel free to comment on that repo if you have other questions etc..

I was wondering if we could also customize the ObjectMapper when creating the listeners. Right now it seems like it comes from pulsar shaded library, I could not figure out a way to customize this through springboot pulsar library. Thanks again for the help

I would suggest opening up another question here on SO or just creating an issue on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-pulsar/issues w/ all the details so as to avoid bifurcating this thread.
